# How do I do multiscale HMM classification?

Tags: classification, hidden-markov-model, boosting, multi-class

I'm using hidden Markov models to classify some accelerometer data. I take the Fourier transform of the raw data at a given window length, and then train an HMM for each class, and every test instance is classified as the class corresponding with the HMM giving the highest log likelihood.

Now, I want to try considering multiple scales/window lengths at once.

The approaches I tried so far:

1. Concatenate the observations for different window length in the time dimension.
2. Add the observations for different window length as additional features
3. Train an HMM for each window length and take the product of loglikelihoods across scales

The results of the first two were extremely poor (chance level, basically, but I suspect there is a bug) and the third was mediocre (roughly equal to the worst single scale results).

Any idea how I might improve this? Could I be doing something completely wrong? Which of the first two approaches is better?

And is the product of loglikelihoods a sensible thing to use, or would I be better off with some sort of boosting, for example?

Your advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you want to combine independent likelihoods, use product.  If you want to combine independent log likelihoods, use sum.

Answer (score 1):

It is generally not a good idea to use generative models, like HMMs, to perform a classification task.

A better approach is to use a discriminative classifier that relies on a Kernel function (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_trick) between examples. For your application, a basic Kernel function that would probably work well would be a dynamic time-warping score between sequences. There are many ways to combine separate Kernel functions into a single Kernel, so this technique would allow you to incorporate multiple window lengths.

An example of an effective application of this technique is with alignment kernels (similar to dynamic time warping) for classifying biological sequences. The Local Alignment Kernel - http://sunflower.kuicr.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~hiroto/project/homology.html - is still one of the top performers in this domain.

Comment: Thanks, very interesting. I assume I would apply the kernel after Fourier transform, right? Otherwise I imagine the temporal information would become completely unreliable.

Comment: Either the raw or transformed data might work. You should probably try both.